# Why is my call to (mobx) extendObservable not triggering a re-render?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx

Here is the code -- pretty sure it is something about extendObservable that I just don't get, but been staring at it for quite a while now. When addSimpleProperty runs, it seems to update the object, but it doesn't trigger a render.

```
const {observable, action, extendObservable} = mobx;
const {observer} = mobxReact;
const {Component} = React;
class TestStore {
    @observable mySimpleObject = {};

    @action addSimpleProperty = (value) => {
        extendObservable(this.mySimpleObject, {newProp: value});
    }
}

@observer
class MyView extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleAddSimpleProperty = this.handleAddSimpleProperty.bind(this);
}
handleAddSimpleProperty(e) {
    this.props.myStore.addSimpleProperty("newpropertyvalue");
}

render() { 
    var simpleObjectString =JSON.stringify(this.props.myStore.mySimpleObject);
    return (<div>     
       <h3> Simple Object</h3>
       {simpleObjectString}
       <br/>
       <button onClick={this.handleAddSimpleProperty}>Add Simple Property</button>
    </div>);
    }
}

const store = new TestStore();
ReactDOM.render(<MyView myStore={store} />,    document.getElementById('mount'));
store.mySimpleObject = {prop1: "property1", prop2: "property2"};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is brought up in the [**Common pitfalls & best practices**](https://mobx.js.org/best/pitfalls.html) section of the documentation:

> MobX observable objects do not detect or react to property assignments
>   that weren't declared observable before. So MobX observable objects
>   act as records with predefined keys. You can use
>   `extendObservable(target, props)` to introduce new observable
>   properties to an object. However object iterators like `for .. in` or
>   `Object.keys()` won't react to this automatically. If you need a
>   dynamically keyed object, for example to store users by id, create
>   observable _map_s using
>   [**observable.map**](https://mobx.js.org/refguide/map.html).

So instead of using `extendObservable` on an observable object, you could just add a new key to an observable map.

**Example**

```
const {observable, action} = mobx;
const {observer} = mobxReact;
const {Component} = React;
class TestStore {
  mySimpleObject = observable.map({});

  @action addSimpleProperty = (value) => {
    this.mySimpleObject.set(value, {newProp: value});
  }
}

@observer
class MyView extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleAddSimpleProperty = this.handleAddSimpleProperty.bind(this);
  }
  handleAddSimpleProperty(e) {
    this.props.myStore.addSimpleProperty("newpropertyvalue");
  }

  render() { 
    var simpleObjectString = this.props.myStore.mySimpleObject.values();
    return (
      <div>     
        <h3> Simple Object</h3>
        {simpleObjectString.map(e => e.newProp)}
        <br/>
        <button onClick={this.handleAddSimpleProperty}>Add Simple Property</button>
     </div>
    );
  }
}

const store = new TestStore();
ReactDOM.render(<MyView myStore={store} />, document.getElementById('mount'));
```

Comment: Yes, I saw this in the docs, and did verify myself that maps do work. But then what use is extendObservable()? It looked like its purpose was to make new properties on simple objects (not maps) observable...

Comment: @tristan It is used to add observable properties to any object. It is just that observers will not react to new observable properties being added with `extendObservable` once the objects are already observed.